# -bash: /usr/sbin/mail: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, symbolic-link

I've been having mail issues for a little while now and decided that today I was going to fix them! Well now I'm stuck. The issue was, when I type `mail` it doesn't display my mail, looking at my symlinks mail was linked to `msmtp`. I tried to update the symlink to `postfix` instead, but that isn't working and a `strace` run is telling me that it is working:

```
sudo strace ln -sf /usr/sbin/mail /usr/sbin/postfix
execve("/bin/ln", ["ln", "-sf", "/usr/sbin/mail", "/usr/sbin/postfix"], [/* 13 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x136f000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=62599, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 62599, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9edbd88000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\t\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1868984, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9edbd87000
mmap(NULL, 3971488, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9edb7a9000
mprotect(0x7f9edb969000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f9edbb69000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c0000) = 0x7f9edbb69000
mmap(0x7f9edbb6f000, 14752, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9edbb6f000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9edbd86000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9edbd85000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f9edbd86700) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9edbb69000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x60c000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f9edbd98000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f9edbd88000, 62599)           = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x136f000
brk(0x1390000)                          = 0x1390000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2981280, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2981280, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9edb4d1000
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/usr/sbin/postfix", 0x7fff872ed280) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/usr/sbin/postfix", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=14, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/sbin/mail", 0x7fff872ed0d0)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
symlink("/usr/sbin/mail", "/usr/sbin/postfix") = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
unlink("/usr/sbin/postfix")             = 0
symlink("/usr/sbin/mail", "/usr/sbin/postfix") = 0
lseek(0, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
close(0)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

However, when I look at the symlink:

```
ls -l /usr/sbin | grep "\->"
...
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           14 Jul 18 09:28 mail -> /usr/bin/msmtp
...
```

I decided to uninstall `msmtp` for good using `sudo apt-get remove msmtp --purge` which worked. I then attempted to create the symlink once more using `sudo ln -sf /usr/sbin/mail /usr/sbin/postfix`. Now whenever I type mail it gives me the following error:

```
 mail
-bash: /usr/sbin/mail: No such file or directory
```

However:

```
sudo find / -iname "mail"
...
/usr/sbin/mail
...
```

What is causing the issue with my `mail` command, and how can I fix it successfully?

---

Output of `sudo find / -iname "postfix"`:

```
sudo find / -iname "postfix"
/etc/ufw/applications.d/postfix
/etc/resolvconf/update-libc.d/postfix
/etc/network/if-up.d/postfix
/etc/network/if-down.d/postfix
/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/postfix
/etc/ppp/ip-down.d/postfix
/etc/insserv.conf.d/postfix
/etc/init.d/postfix
/etc/postfix
/usr/share/doc/postfix
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/postfix
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/postfix
/usr/share/postfix
/usr/sbin/postfix   #<=
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fail2ban/tests/files/logs/postfix
/usr/lib/postfix
/var/spool/postfix
/var/lib/postfix
You have new mail in /home/serveradmin/Maildir
```

Comment: Can you post result of `sudo find / -iname "postfix"`?

Comment: @Fanatique yeah one second

Comment: First thing first: with `sudo ln -sf /usr/sbin/mail /usr/sbin/postfix` you made `postfix` a symlink to `mail`, not the other way around.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Even if I do it the other way around, it still prodices the same results, I thought about that

Comment: As a side note, what is the _actual point_ of symlinking `mail` to `postfix`? They do completely different things! You won't find an interactive mail client in Postfix. (Nor in msmtp, for that matter. They're both commonly symlinked to /usr/sbin/*send*mail instead.)

Comment: The `-f` in your command has overwritten the binary `/usr/sbin/postfix` with a link. Now when you reverse the order there is no binary to link to, though I would have expected an error. You need to reinstall the binary `/usr/sbin/postfix` from a back-up or a reinstall.

Comment: @grawity basically I just want my interactive mail client back.

Comment: @AFH Removing and purging postfix fixed the issue, post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-f` in your command has overwritten the binary `/usr/sbin/postfix` with a link.

When you subsequently reverse the order there is no binary to link to, though I would have expected an error.

You need to reinstall the binary `/usr/sbin/postfix` from a back-up or a reinstall; the correctly ordered `ln -sf /usr/sbin/postfix /usr/sbin/mail` will now give you the link you want.

On Ubuntu 16.04 the normal `mail` program is in `/usr/bin/`, though by default `/usr/sbin/` is earlier in the `PATH` list.